Contract showing metadata in test net but main net shows string (bnb)
I have deployed a contract:

0x10369C1AD1d37DF93B34f2d51f36E8AfDe7A1412

On testnet all works, while the same contract on mainnet returns a string for a value:

0x222AbDe1C70E9AFFc88c2fa8D27487b1f40A485c.

I think it has to do with my flatting of the contract for verification, but verification is same way on testnet and it works.

Can you please elaborate more on what exactly you’re trying to achieve?

Doesn't have anything to do with the method of verification.
Assuming the value in question is tokenURI
On Mainnet it's failing with:
invalid opcode: MCOPY

Testnet must be ahead on EVM version and working opcodes. Compile with an older version from before MCOPY opcode and redeploy.

pre evm-version cancun

